# Timer.periodic does not work correctly with provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to use the method `periodic` of the class `Timer` inside a class which extends of the class `ChangeNotifier` (of the package [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)) making my variable `time` decrease every second.

This works correctly if I don't add the `NotifyListeners` method which  redraws all the widgets that occupy the `time` property, like:

```
class PriceProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _time = 60;

  int get time{
    return _time;
  }

  void chronometer(){//method which activate the timer

    Timer _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer){
      print(DateTime.now());//I print the date so you can see how often the code is executed
      
      _time += -1;//decrease time

      if(_time == 0){
        _time = 60;
      } 

      // notifyListeners(); 
    });
  } 

}
```

Console output (runs every second correctly):
[image: Salida por consola]

On the other hand, if I uncomment the `NotifyListeners` method, the code starts executing more and more times per second exponentially (for example, first it executes once, then twice, then 5, then 9 and so on):
[image: Salida por consola]

Here is the code where I call the method `chronometer`:

```
class PriceWithClock extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PriceProvider priceProvider = Provider.of<PriceProvider>(context);
    priceProvider.chronometer();
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 100.0,
      lineWidth: 5.0,
      percent: 1-priceProvider.time/60,
      center: Text("00:${priceProvider.time}"),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your periodic `Timer`  triggers a widget rebuild, and every time you rebuild your widget, you call your `chronometer` method, which creates an additional periodic `Timer` that also triggers a widget rebuild, .... Each `Timer` will end up creating an additional `Timer` every second, leading to exponential growth.  You must ensure that you have only one `Timer` active; don't create a new one if a `Timer` already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not put the `priceProvider.chronometer();` inside the build method since it will be executed on every `PriceWithClock` widget build. And in your case, it would happen every second.

What you can do, is create a Stateful widget and trigger the chronometer inside the `initState()` method:

```
class PriceWithClock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PriceWithClockState();
}

class _PriceWithClockState extends State<PriceWithClock> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    context.read<PriceProvider>().chronometer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

As for the `build` method, you could use the `context.watch` Provider extension method to listen to the updated `time` value:

```
class _PriceWithClockState extends State<PriceWithClock> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final time = context.watch<PriceProvider>().time;
    
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 100.0,
      lineWidth: 5.0,
      percent: 1 - time / 60,
      center: Text("00:$time"),
    );
  }
}
```

The final result looks like this:

```
class PriceWithClock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PriceWithClockState();
}

class _PriceWithClockState extends State<PriceWithClock> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    context.read<PriceProvider>().chronometer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final time = context.watch<PriceProvider>().time;
    
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 100.0,
      lineWidth: 5.0,
      percent: 1 - time / 60,
      center: Text("00:$time"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer dear.